# Return back host application after submiting form data from WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, redirect, webviewclient

I am developing a android application, Within the application I am 
trying to Load a URL using WEBVIEW. Afer i submit the data in the 
opened webpage, it gets redirected to some other URL. My requirement 
is to get the complete Redirected URL within my android application.

I didnt see any events/ API methods which can be used to notify URL 
Redirect.

Are there any way to listen for URL redirects within my application 
and then retrieve the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can identify the redirection using webClient just set webclient on your webview

like below

```
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()       
            {
                 @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
                {

                    //do your stuff here 
                    if(url.equalsIgnoreCase("your redirect url "))
                    {
                      return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Comment: i was solve same problem before you answer any way right answer